# flacards and forloop is working but not with tikz foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, option-clash

My flashcard with `\forloop` is working after your help.
I try it with `\foreach` (tikz) but it's not working.
The pdf files contain only one flash card in the bottom right corner, the 24th card and the 48th,...

The minimal non-working example is :

```
    \documentclass{flacards}
    \usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
    \usepackage{tikz} 
    \begin{document}

    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,50}{\card{a}{b}}

    \end{document}
```

but the `\forloop` version is working :

```
    \documentclass{flacards}
    \usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
    \usepackage{forloop} 
    \begin{document}

    \newcounter{compteura}
    \forloop{compteura}{1}{\value{compteura} < 11}{\card{a}{b}}

    \end{document}
```

I prefer use `tikz` for the math possibility.
Until such time I use package `calc` for doing math on counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem is in the fact that `\foreach` does everything inside a group and this, for some reason, conflicts with the card production of **flacards**; indeed just the last card in each page is actually printed.

In order to see if my assertion is right, I ran the following test:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {1}{\def\pippo{X}}
\show\pippo
\stop
```

and TeX prompted

> `> \pippo=undefined.`
>   `l.5 \show\pippo`

Unfortunately, also removing the group started by `\foreach` seems to do nothing (it's quite possible that other groups are used).

If you need the `\foreach` function only in cases such as `{1,2,...,50}` it's easy to replace it with other loops, as you already know. If the "list" processing is needed, please update your question. With **etoolbox** it's quite handy to process lists of values.

Comment: thank, I understand the point. Your explications are very clear.I will try to use the other package flashcards.cls, or forloop with flacard.cls.